# Is IPv6 configuration important?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, ipv6

My website's server currently uses IPv4 only.
I know IPv6 will be important in the future, but:

1. Is it important to use IPv6 now?
2. Does my website get less visitors if the server does not support IPv6?

Comment: You should be pressuring your ISP to support it even if you don't need it right at this moment. Even if you don't' require it.  That way you will the ability to use it when you need it.  ISPs won't start using it until they get pressured enough for them to realize there is actually a need.

Comment: Yes, if only to give yourself exposure to how things work with IPv6. You're going to have to deal with it sooner or later - why not start now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately? No, it won't make much difference. Most people in the world have an IPv4 address, so you won't miss out.

But at the same time - the pressure to do IPv6 is steadily increasing as IP addresses are becoming exhausted. It won't be too much longer before there'll be significant numbers of people who can't speak to IPv4 only services.

Comment: Most people will be able to use IPv4 for the foreseeable future, but more and more of that IPv4 traffic will be going through ISP NATs which are becoming a single point of failure and will limit performance. Making your website reachable through IPv6 will make sure your visitors will have the option to use IPv6 instead of the crippled IPv4.

Comment: IPv6 at the edge?  I reckon I'll be retired before that happens.

Comment: Depends on business drivers IMO. IPv6 has been 'soon' for about 10 years now. It's a critical mass problem - we're getting closer, but until we hit that critical mass... there'll be workarounds that postpone the inevitable. I'm pretty sure there's large chunks of address space that's allocated, but is effectively isolated from the rest of the 'net, because of all the organisations that got themselves a class B back when that was the done thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a significant users accessing your site, then some of them will be doing so through a NAT. And using a NAT for this does decrease reliability of the connection.

If there are any competitors to your service, then reliability of the site does affect how many users use your site and how many use your competitors. And unless the government has granted you a monopoly, then you likely do have competitors.

If you can ask if enabling IPv6 affect the reliability of your service. Back in 2009 the answer would have been that enabling IPv6 negatively impact the reliability of your service in the users experience. In reality this was due to misconfiguration of the user's own network, but they would still blame your site.

Since then things have changed. The problems got enough attention to improve the situation. Major service providers have enabled IPv6 on their websites. And IPv4 addresses have run out. 3 og out 5 RIRs are rationing IPv4 addresses.

This means there are fewer people who will experience a problem due to IPv6 being enabled, and there are users who have native IPv6 connectivity without any NAT involved who at the same time have to go through some sort of carrier grade NAT to reach you over IPv4. Those users will get a better experience if you enable IPv6.

Currently the difference may not be significant. But I believe we have crossed the point where enabling IPv6 is an improvement to the user experience rather than the opposite. And it will only continue going in that direction, as IPv4 is going to get less reliable until it is unreliable enough for the average user to notice the difference between IPv4 and IPv6 and start demanding IPv6.

If your hosting provider doesn't support IPv6 you should start looking for another hosting provider. I personally have moved the last service I was responsible for away from a provider with no IPv6 support.

IPv6 may not be important for you now. But it will be, and the sooner you start, the more ready you'll be that day.

Comment: Thing is - IPv6 has been just around the corner for 10 years now. We're getting steadily nearer to 'critical mass' but until we do, no one's going to take the risk of excommunicating significant fractions of the internet.

Comment: @Sobrique It's not about risk, it is about incentives. Lots of people have been in a situation where they could do something about it. And lots of people could have had a benefit from IPv6 being deployed. It just so happens, that things have been organized in a way where there was too small overlap among those groups. Had IPv4 rationing been introduced a decade ago - but only for IPv4 only networks, then most of the internet would have been IPv6 only by now. And it could have happened with less breakage along the way than we are seeing now.